# How to prevent 'no username' in django?

Tags: django

This is what my registration form looks like:

[image: Registration form]

I want to make it so that if the user doesn't write anything in the given text boxes, a warning sign pops up and say that ' a username must be inputted' or something like that

but when i click the submit button, Value error occurs, saying that "The given username must be set"

```py
def register(request):

    context = {
        'error_message': None,
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or Person.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                context['error_message'] = '이미 사용중인 아이디입니다.'
                return render(request, 'UserAdministration/register.html', context)
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() or Person.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                context['error_message'] = '이미 사용중인 이메일입니다.'
                return render(request, 'UserAdministration/register.html ', context)
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    password=password1,
                    email=email,
                    username=username
                    )
                user.save()

                masked_username = generate_masked_username.generate_masked_username(username)

                person = Person.objects.create(
                    username=username,
                    masked_username=masked_username,
                    email=email,
                    password=password1
                )
                person.save()

                return redirect('login')
        else:
            context['error_message'] = '비밀번호가 맞지 않습니다.'
            return render(request, 'UserAdministration/register.html', context)
        # return redirect('/')
        # originally was homepage.html. Doesn't know if this changed anything. just a note
    else:
        return render(request, 'UserAdministration/register.html', context)
```

This is my code... anybody know how to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) are for. You should use a Form (or ModelForm) rather than building the form and using `request.POST` manually. Then you will get better errors. [These docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#creating-forms-from-models) will be especially useful.

A quick example:

Form:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ["username", "email", "password"]
```

View:

```py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import RegistrationForm

class UserRegistrationView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    template_name = "registration/register.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
```

This will get you most of the way there, you just need to add a custom field and some logic for the password2 validation and handle whatever the masked username stuff is.

Registration is such a common workflow however, that you can also use a package like [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/) to handle the details for you, and you can just override what you need for your custom logic where it's needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment appreciate it bud